# Push Notification issue in iOS 13

Tags: ios, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I am using Remote Push Notification feature in my iOS application. Currently i am facing a strange issue. I am receiving push notifications into devices which are have iOS < 13 but those devices which are have iOS 13 not getting push notifications.

I searched a lot over stackoverflow and other platform and found that apple suggested that in iOS 13 we need to add "apns-push-type" into header as well as in payload body. I have done it over server side where i write push notifications related code.

I developed my application using XCode 11 and using FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) service to send push notifications.

```
public function pushSurveyorNotificationios(){

  $url = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
  $token = 'XXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX';
  $serverKey = 'XXXX-YYYYY-ZZZZZ';
  $title = "Push Notification Testing";
  $body = "Push Notification Testing detail";
  $notification = array('title' =>$title , 'body' => $body, 'sound' => 'default', 'badge' => '1');
  $arrayToSend = array('to' => $token, 'notification' => $notification, 'apns' => array('headers' => array('apns-push-type' => 'alert')));
  $json = json_encode($arrayToSend);
  //die($json);
  $headers = array();
  $headers[] = 'apns-push-type: alert';
  $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
  $headers[] = 'Authorization: key='. $serverKey;
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,

  "POST");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
  //Send the request
  $response = curl_exec($ch);

  //Close request
  if ($response === FALSE) {
  die('FCM Send Error: ' . curl_error($ch));
  }
  curl_close($ch);
  return $response;
}
```

Above function i am using to send push notifications to devices.

I got this link over apple for iOS 13 push notifications issue.

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/118420